# Installing rmagick gem on Amezon AMI server getting error for ImageMagick dependencies

Tags: rmagick

Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
current directory: /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rmagick-4.2.2/ext/RMagick
```

/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin/ruby -I /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20210806-10706-10mubyf.rb extconf.rb
checking for brew... no
checking for pacman... no
checking for Ruby version >= 2.3.0... yes
checking for pkg-config... yes
checking for outdated ImageMagick version (<= 6.7.7)... no
checking for gcc... yes
checking for **GNUC**... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:467:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError) You have to install development tools first. from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:585:in` block in try_compile'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:534:in `with_werror' from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:585:in` try_compile'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:852:in `macro_defined?' from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:994:in` block in have_macro'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:959:in `block in checking_for' from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in` block (2 levels) in postpone'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in `open' from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in` block in postpone'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in `open' from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:357:in` postpone'
from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:958:in `checking_for' from /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:993:in` have_macro'
from extconf.rb:99:in `configure_compile_options' from extconf.rb:19:in` initialize'
from extconf.rb:398:in `new' from extconf.rb:398:in` '

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0/rmagick-4.2.2/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/rmagick-4.2.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0/rmagick-4.2.2/gem_make.out

Answer (score 1):

1. sudo yum -y install ImageMagick ImageMagick-devel
2. convert -version
   Output:

Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-68 Q16 x86_64 2021-02-03 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2019 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP(3.1)
Delegates (built-in): bzlib fontconfig freetype gslib jng jpeg lcms ltdl lzma png ps tiff wmf x xml zlib
3. gem install rmagick
if you still get the error follow below commands

1. sudo ln -s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-amazon-linux/4.8.5/libgomp.spec /usr/lib64/libgomp.spec
2. sudo ln -s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-amazon-linux/4.8.5/libgomp.a /usr/lib64/libgomp.a
3. sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libgomp.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib64/libgomp.so
   And run again gem install rmagick and its all done.

You can find the link below
https://senrenseyo.com/20210811/rails6_rmagick/